# Selenium cucumber not running in headless mode

Tags: selenium, cucumber, headless

I have added all headless condition in code still while running i am getting chrome browser gets launched

I tried the below code and expected it should work

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Set the "headless" flag
options.addArguments("--headless");
// Create a new ChromeDriver instance with the headless option
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Create  ChromeOptions object.

2.- Set as Headless as argument.

3.- Get the WebDriver.

```
final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("Headless");
final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Selenium 4.8.0](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/), correct way of setting the headless mode is like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://selenium.dev");
driver.quit();
```